# more efficient way to display single value from mySQL db?

Tags: php, mysql, random

I Am just learning PHP and loving it so far. I have this code that is pulling a single random ID from a database, but the only way I know how to do it is with a while loop which seems not very efficient.  Can anybody show me how to spice up this code?  As you can see, I am just trying to assign $pollquestionid a random active ID from the DB.

```
///this gets a random active poll number
    $sql12 = "SELECT id FROM poll WHERE removed = 0 AND active = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $result12 = mysql_query($sql12);
    while ($myrow12 = mysql_fetch_array($result12)) {
    $pollquestionid = $myrow12['id'];
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you're getting only 1 record, what's wrong with while loop? It'll iterate only once, no harm done there.

Comment: why do you think it's not very efficient? it's excessive code, yes, but nothing actually bad in it

Comment: Why do you need the while loop at all? Why can't you just use the result given by `mysql_fetch_array($result12);`?

Comment: @syrion: it is good to check if there was a result at all (else this will raise a warning e.g. in an empty table); you're correct that `while` is a bit unintuitive - `if` would be sufficient there - but not harmful.

Comment: @piskvor: Yes, I said that poorly.  I do think that `while` is a mistake, though; it makes the code less readable.

Comment: @syrion: You are correct that it obscures the intent, yes. OTOH, it is simply extensible, should you decide that you now need 5 samples instead of 1; but that's just pure nitpicking on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think it will matter that much when you loop through it, it will not add any perfomance boost since you are limiting you query.

You could try this function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

PHP.net is a great resource when you are trying to learn PHP, check the "See also" functions, they might come in handy when you want to do something a little different

```
$sql12 = "SELECT id FROM poll WHERE removed = 0 AND active = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result12 = mysql_query($sql12);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$randomid = $row[0];
```

Comment: ahhhh mysql_fetch_row eh? That is what I wanted to know.  Love it! That was my main concern, performance boost.  I can already tell with PHP that there is more than one way to skin a cat. I just want to learn how to skin the cat the best way!

Comment: @Narf performance boost? Where do you get performance boost here?

Answer (score 1):

Just as comments say there's really nothing wrong with the code. I would just use "if" instead of "while" and leave it at that.

Comment: I am with ya! Thanks for the input. I switched to IF instead of WHILE My problem with it is like Shrapnel said, it IS excessive code. 

My questioning was basically why do I need mysql_fetch_array all I need is one number that doesn't even need to be in an array?   Does that make sense? (Again, noob here.)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong there - if you're limiting the result to 1 row (which you are), then you'll get at most 1 row back, therefore your while loop will run at most once. You could rewrite with `if` instead of `while`, but that's deeply in the field of "pointless microoptimization":

```
if ($myrow12 = mysql_fetch_array($result12)) {
    $pollquestionid = $myrow12['id'];
}
```

The main problem will be actually on the DB server: as your `ORDER BY` clause can't build on any index, it will 1) sort the table into another, temporary table (using disk if it's large enough; disk access is sloooooow), 2) take the top row 3) throw away the temp table. *Slightly* inefficient there. Milen Kostadinov proposes a more efficient version of the query [in the comments to MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html#c7946):

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, ... , colN FROM tab 
  WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM tab 
      WHERE conditions 
      ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT m
  )
```

What happens there is that first, the subquery runs - only the numerical IDs are being sorted (much faster than the whole table), and then *m* ones from that set are returned and used to request the relevant rows from the whole table (also fast).

Answer (score 1):

The question seems quite vague, it's impossible to tell what's being your concern - a negligible issue with while loop or real existing problem with not so efficient `order by rand` issue.

For the latter please use search, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+rand will give you couple solutions.

For the former, short answer would be just "don't use while"

```
$sql12 = "SELECT id FROM poll WHERE removed = 0 AND active = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result12 = mysql_query($sql12);
$myrow12 = mysql_fetch_array($result12);
$pollquestionid = $myrow12['id'];
```

however, one can look a little deeper into the problem.
in fact, we got rid of one line but still have 4. Why not to make it just one:

```
$poll_qid=dbgetvar("SELECT id FROM poll WHERE removed = 0 AND active = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";)
```

To use *a user-defined function* would be really efficient in terms of code code shortening!
As simple function as this one:

```
function dbgetvar($query){
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    trigger_error("dbget: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
    return FALSE;
  } else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    if (!$row) return NULL;
    return $row[0];
  }
}
```

will greatly reduce your code!
Just put it into your whatever config/library file and use whenever you need single value out from SQL query.

With a little improvement you can make this function even support some sort of placeholders, saving you manual escaping in case of some dynamical data:

```
function dbgetvar(){
  $args  = func_get_args();
  $query = array_shift($args);
  foreach ($args as $key => $val) {
    $args[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
  }
  $query = str_replace("%s","'%s'",$query); 
  $query = vsprintf($query, $args);

  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    trigger_error("dbgetarr: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
    return FALSE;
  } else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    if (!$row) return NULL;
    return $row[0];
  }
}
```

So, it can be used this way

```
$name = dbgetvar("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=%d",$_GET['id']);
```

or

```
$name = dbgetvar("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name=%s AND surname = %s",
                 $_GET['name'],
                 $_GET['surname']);
```

without any danger, saving you manual escaping.
these marks being called "placeholders" and considered to be very safe and useful approach to handle SQL queries

Of course, one can use not only this one, but whole family of functions, to get single row, or array of rows, or array of single values... and eventually combine them into class.

This is called *"programming"* and there is very little of it on Stackoverflow...

Comment: WOW, you gave me the simple AND the advanced. Very much appreciated. I never even thought about making a function. :)